# Using memory-mapped files from within a .so (shared object)

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, mmap

I am getting a segfault when accessing shared memory (memory mapped file, using a fixed address of 0x60000000 ) from within a share object (.so).

We have many applications accessing this shared memory without difficulty.
My app is different in that I create a small .so with it and the .so is the one calling mmap and accessing the shared memory.

The mmap() returns just fine.  My requested address is returned back properly.  But as soon as I try to access the memory from within this .so, it seg faults.

I can't figure out what is unique about a .so that would prevent it from accessing shared memory this way.

Anyone have thoughts?

Comment: Nothing special with correctly built (`-fPIC`) shared objects Compile with all warnings & debug info. Use the `gdb` debugger. Show some code, we cannot guess it. Use `strace`

Comment: Are you sure that the mapped file still exists when you try to access the memory location? You can get `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS` if accessing that portion of the file doesn't make sense anymore (e.g. file was deleted, or shrinked in size)

Comment: Used -fPIC and confirmed the file exists.   This is a legacy system, so small code snippet is too difficult.   But these questions are good.

Answer (score 2):

In general, accessing `mmap`ed memory from a shared library is *in no way different* from accessing it from a main executable, and you are likely barking up the wrong tree. That said, this:

> memory mapped file, using a fixed address of `0x60000000`

is generally a *very bad idea*, because you have no control over what (if anything) was `mmap`ed there before. A `MAP_FIXED` mapping will simply remove any previous mapping that existed. *If* your library itself happens to be mapped there, then you'll replace the library `.text`, or `.data`, and the result is almost certain to be a mysterious crash.

Comment: All of us on this legacy system concur with a fixed address being "unpleasant".   It was there to support old Fortran apps which are required to have fixed addresses for shared mem to work.   But if the address wasn't available, would mmap() fail??     Besides, another program is running that already mapped the address for me.  So, I would think memory is up and ready to go.

Comment: @Spaceman5 No, `mmap(..., MAP_FIXED...)` will not fail if the address already has a mapping, it will blow away existing mapping instead. And the fact that another program mapped the address is irrelevant: shared library placement is on *per process* basis.